# Let $p$ and $q$ be prime such that $p\not\equiv1\pmod q$. Determine the possible number of solutions $x$ to the equation $x^q=b$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to answer the question: Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that $p\not\equiv 1 \pmod q$. Let $b\in\mathbb{F}_p$. Determine the possible number of solutions $x$ to the equation $x^q = b$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Does this number of solutions depend on $b$?

I don't really understand how to go about this. I've tried reading the book we are given and it still makes no sense. I think I need to out how $x^q$ relates to $p$ but I don't understand that either. I don't see any theorems or anything on this topic.

I currently think it is saying I need to find out the number of times the same solution $x^q$ appears in $\mathbb{F}_p$ but I don't know how to do that either.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you learned that the multiplicative group $\Bbb F_p^*$ is cyclic? If you choose a generator $g$ and write $x=g^s$ and $b=g^t$, then you'll get an equation in the exponents of both sides modulo $p-1$.

Comment: No we have learned very little about finite fields and we have only learned the basics up to chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Do you at least know Fermat's little theorem?  I.e. for any $x \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, $x^{p-1} = 1$?

Comment: Yes we do because that is how we find our multiplicative inverses @BrianMoehring

Comment: And can you see that $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ implies there are some $A,B$ such that $Aq + B(p-1) = 1$?  (if so, you have enough tools to actually solve for $x$ in terms of $b$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring So would I use a mix of the Euclidean and Fermat's? I don't quite understand though how I would solve for A,B in this case. Would A,B be my number of solutions?

Comment: You don't solve for $A,B$ here.  Their existence is given by repeated applications of the division algorithm, so if you had a particular $p,q$ and wanted to find a corresponding $A,B$, you could just repeat that algorithm.  The only facts that matter about them here is that $A,B$ are integers and we may assume $A > 0$.

Comment: It would be best to take an example; $p=67$ and $q=11$, it doesn't work (why?); so another one.

Comment: it doesn't work because $67=66+1=6\times11+1\equiv 1[11]$; here $p\equiv 1[q]$; it doesn't work :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen so if p mod q = 1 then it will noy work we need p mod q > 1?

Comment: The statement asks to consider $p$ and $q$ such that $(p-1)mod q \neq \color{red}0$; I leave you to look for examples and reflect

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen so we need p-1 to not be divisible by q

Answer (score 4):

We use two facts:

- By Fermat's little theorem, we know that if $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is nonzero, then $x^{p-1} = 1$.  As a simple corollary, we may show that if $a,b$ are integers such that $a > 0$ and $a+b(p-1) > 0$, then $x^{a+b(p-1)} = x^a$ for every $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ (this is one way to drop the assumption of $x$ being nonzero).
- Since $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, we see that $q$ does not divide $p-1$.  Since $q$ is a prime, we see that the greatest common divisor of $q$ and $p-1$ is $1$.  By the usual application of the division algorithm, there exist integers $A,B$ such that $Aq + B(p-1) = 1$, and in particular, we may assume $A > 0$.

This allows us to write $x^q = b$ as
$$x^q = b^1 = b^{Aq+B(p-1)} = b^{Aq} = (b^A)^q$$

Therefore one solution is $x = b^A$.  This directly shows that there's *at least* one solution for every $b\in \mathbb{F}_p$, or in other words, the $q$th-power map, $$\mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p : x \mapsto x^q,$$ is surjective.

Finally, since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is *finite*, any surjective map $\mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p$ is automatically a bijection, so $x^q = b$ has exactly one solution $x$ for any $b \in \mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: for example, with $p=13, q=11, b=\bar9 \in \mathbb{F}_{13} : B=1, A=-1, \bar9=\bar9^{-1\times 11+1\times12}=(\bar9^{-1})^{11}=\bar3^{11}$(I hope the example will be useful to OP)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how we turn b into the b^Aq + B(p-1) expression is it because we have b^1 and we know that Aq + B(p-1) = 1 from the extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Also why can we drop the B(p-1)?

Comment: @Anonymous98737943 To your first comment, yes, since $Aq + B(p-1) = 1$ is an identity in $\mathbb{Z}$, $b^1 = b^{Aq+B(p-1)}$.  To your second comment, that is exactly the corollary to Fermat's little theorem I mentioned in the first bullet point.  Specifically, if $b \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $$b^{Aq+B(p-1)} = b^{Aq}b^{B(p-1)} = b^{Aq}(b^{p-1})^B = b^{Aq}1^B = b^{Aq}.$$  If $b=0$, then since $Aq+B(p-1) > 0$ and $Aq>0$, $$b^{Aq+B(p-1)} = 0 = b^{Aq}.$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see thanks!!